# objProcess.Terminate not Found specific to iexplore.exe

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

When terminating internet explorer within VBA I'm using the following code sourced (more or less) from stackoverflow:

```
Sub IE_Sledgehammer()
    Dim objWMI As Object, objProcess As Object, objProcesses As Object
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts://.")
    Set objProcesses = objWMI.ExecQuery( _
        "SELECT * FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = 'iexplore.exe'")
    MsgBox "iexplore.exe processes = " & objProcesses.Count
    For Each objProcess In objProcesses
        Call objProcess.Terminate
    Next
    Set objProcesses = Nothing: Set objWMI = Nothing
End sub
```

The number of processes returned is "2" (which is correct) but in the first iteration of the For loop, when the first iexplore.exe is terminated that also terminates the second process and so in the second loop iteration a 'not found' error occurs. I understand that this is because closing one iexplorer.exe process closes all iexplore.exe tasks.

My question is, how can I reference and terminate only the first 'objprocess' in the objprocesses list OR force the For loop to exit after one iteration?

Comment: If you think my suggestion can be the answer to this question then I suggest you accept it as an answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Do you mean you want to close the first tab or IE window?

I suggest you create an object of Shell and loop through IE windows.

You can close the first IE window and exit the loop or you can match the title of the IE window and close that specific IE window.

You need to add the reference to **Microsoft Shell Controls and Automation** and **Microsoft Internet Controls**.

[image]

Code:

```
Sub demo()

Dim oShellWin As Shell
Dim oWin As Object
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer

    Set oShellWin = New Shell

      For Each objIE In oShellWin.Windows

        If TypeName(objIE.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then

            'Debug.Print objIE.Document.Title
            If objIE.Document.Title = "Bing" Then 'User can modify the title here...
                objIE.Quit
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next objIE

End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Further, you can try to modify the code as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Deepak, I appreciate your response but I haven't marked my question as answered as it doesn't adress either of my questions. As I state, I'm looking to quit the iexplore.exe process(es) not a particular tab or window. In my code it 'finds' two iexplore.exe processes but after entering the loop and terminating the first one, the second one also terminates and so in the second loop I get a 'not found' error and the script halts.

Comment: I've also since found that in Task Manager, one iexplore.exe task is labelled as "Internet Explorer" and a second task is labelled as "Internet Exploere (32 bit)". If the task labelled "Internet Explorer" is (manually) ended then the second task labelled "Internet Explorer (32bit)" automatically ends as well. So, ideally, I would like to just kill the first task and ignore the second task which will presumably close by itself. I should also mention that I am invoking IE as not visible (IE.Visible = False).

Comment: I suggest you try to provide a snapshot of that 2 processes in your task manager. It can help us to understand the issue properly. So that we can know whether it can be done with the above code or we need to modify the code.

Comment: At the link is a screenshot of my task manager entries while the script is running. The (32bit) task is the one doing the work but if I kill the non 32bit task both go away.https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKVcL.jpg

Comment: I still think that it is better to close specific tabs. the reason is you will not know that the desired process you want to close will be the first IE process in the list of the task manager.

Comment: Your code doesn't work at all for me. I can see now it calls objIE.quit which I've found in the past often doesn't work (although occasionally it does) when IE.visible is set to True and that's why I had a specific sub to kill the iexplore.exe task(s). It's frustrating and there seems to be an element of randomness when using either method.

Comment: How those IE processes created? What tabs are opened in it? what exactly did you try? You also need to modify the title of the tab in the code. Did you modify that? Please provide detailed information about your testing. It can help us to understand it properly.

Comment: OK, so I'll attemp to post my sub for invoking, using, and then closing IE (website and Logon cred's are blanked).
But basically the sub navigates to the website logon page, logs in, and then reads a series of site specific URL's (ie. pages) from a previously opened Excel sheet to gather some info using another sub ( Call GetHTMLContents) and then logouts out and closes IE.
As you will see in the code I now specifically look for the tab title (there's only one tab open) and perform an IE.quit. I then call the IE_sledgehammer routine to identify and close any remaining iexplore.exe tasks.

Comment: The IE.quit does work 'some times' and then the IE_sledgehammer call simply exit's, other times though IE_sledghammer identifies two iexplore.exe tasks still running and attempts to kill them.

Comment: However, I do want to re-iterate, that my problem seems to fundamentally be an IE issue, in that:
1) IE sometimes doesn't shut down completely after an IE.QUIT.
2) in IE_sledgehammer, when I kill the first identified task IE also closes the 2nd (child?) task and so using a loop in sledgehammer doesn't seem like the right approach but I can't work out how to NOT run the 2nd loop iteration OR how to identify and kill only the first iexplore.exe task. EDIT: I can't post my code as it doesn't seem to be possible in a comment?

Comment: If I see the snapshot of the IE process you had shared in the comment then I can see that those are 2 IE processes and not a child IE process. You are using For Each loop not a for a loop. For each loop get executed for each IE process. I also noticed that IE.terminate will terminate all the IE processes. I did not get any workaround for it. I will search further and if I get any useful information then I will try to provide you. Thanks for your understanding.